# How to check if zipfile is not already closed

Tags: python, python-zipfile

What is the best way in Python to check if a ZipFile object is not already closed?

For the moment I am doing this in a class:

```
try:
    self.zf.open(archive_name).close()
except RuntimeError:
    self.zf = zipfile.ZipFile(self.path)

with self.zf.open(archive_name) as f: 
    # do stuff...
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: What do you mean by "already"? When can the file be closed by whom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally, there is an open file pointer called `fp` that get's cleared on close; you can test for that yourself too:

```
if not self.zf.fp:
    self.zf = zipfile.ZipFile(self.path)
```

See the [`zipfile` module source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/zipfile.py); the `open` method raises the `RuntimeError` exception if `not self.fp` is True.

Note that relying on such internal, undocumented implementations can be hairy; if future implementations change your code will break, perhaps in subtle ways. Make sure you have good test coverage for your project.

Alternatively, you could create a ZipFile subclass and override the `.close` method to track the state, which would be less at risk of breaking due to internal changes:

```
class MyZipFile(zipfile.ZipFile):
    closed = False
    def close(self):
        self.closed = True
        super(MyZipFile, self).close()
```

and

```
if self.zf.closed:
    self.zf = MyZipFile(self.path)
```

*with thanks to aknuds1 for the suggestion*.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any other indication whether a ZipFile is closed unfortunately. Maybe it'd be an idea to subclass ZipFile and override close() with a method that indicates that the instance has been closed?

Comment: @aknuds1: That's not the issue; calling `.close()` multiple times works fine. It's the *open* call that is the problem for the OP.

Comment: My idea was to remedy that there's no public state indicating whether a ZipFile has been closed, by subclassing ZipFile you could implement that state yourself.